# How to sum up the sums of grouped results with SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sum

I am new to SQL and have no clue how to solve my problem. I've got a column of names [name]), a column of integer values that I wanna sum up ([Values]) and another column of integer values ([Day]). 
I want to sum up the values grouped by name for each day. So for example if there is a name "Chris" with value 4 on day 1 and there is another entry "Chris" with value 2 on day 3, I want to show the sum of chris on day 1 (4) and on day 2 (4+2=6).

So far I've only worked it out to sum up the values in total (see code below).

```
select Name,
Sum(Values) AS SumValues 
from X1
Group by Name;
```

but as in the example above ("chris") I wanna sum them up, showing the sum for each name on each day (the sum from day 1 until day x).

Answer (score 2):

With sum() window function:

```
select name, day,
  sum(value) over (partition by name order by day) total
from tablename
```

For this table:

```
create table tablename(name varchar(10), day int, value int);
insert into tablename(name, day, value) values
('Chris', 1, 2), ('Chris', 2, 4), ('Chris', 3, 8), 
('Alice', 1, 5), ('Alice', 2, 10), ('Alice', 3, 20);
```

the results are:

```
> name  | day | total
> :---- | --: | ----:
> Alice |   1 |     5
> Alice |   2 |    15
> Alice |   3 |    35
> Chris |   1 |     2
> Chris |   2 |     6
> Chris |   3 |    14
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=c3d376297dc2f01580cb4c79e2a96662).

Comment: Thank you for your help thats actually excatly what I've asked for but I've expressed myself not clearly enough. Because there is actually a further column with names (name2) I need to follow the original sequence of the data because each name is uniquely assigned to another name in another column of the same row. Then, In every row the names both are assigned to a specific value of this row. Later, I want to calculate with each pair of names respectively values (sum of values) further results.

Comment: This code answers the question as you posted it. If there is a different requirement then post a new question and explain what you want.